# How do I get Permission to post to Facebook Page Wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

After reading the developers.facebook.com for the past few hours I just can't seem to figure out how to get my Facebook Page to allow permission for me to post to its wall from a Django Website?

Answer (score 0):

you must give related permissions to your app(publish_stream,manage pages)
then you can post to page as page

posting to page as page if you have  page's access_token can be like this:

```
   include_once ('src/facebook.php');/// include sdk
    ////// config The sdk
        @ $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         ));
    try{        
    $post=$facebook->api('PAGE_ID/feed/','POST',array(
    'message' => '$message',
    'link'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/link.php?link=',
    'picture'=> 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'name'=>'XXXXXX',
    'description'=>'yes',
    'access_token'=>'PAGE ACCESS TOKEN'

    ));
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getType();
    echo '<br />';
    echo $e->getMessage();
     }
```

& if you dont have access token (you need above permissions again) i think this can help you

```
   include_once ('src/facebook.php');/// include sdk
    ////// config The sdk
        @ $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         ));
$facebook->destroySession();
    try{        
    $post=$facebook->api('PAGE ID/feed/','POST',array(
    'message' => '$message',
    'link'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/link.php?link=',
    'picture'=> 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'name'=>'XXXXXX',
    'description'=>'yes',

    ));
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getType();
    echo '<br />';
    echo $e->getMessage();
     }
```

to learn how to get page's access_token check this link up:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts